# The authentication or decryption has failed.

Tags: ubuntu, mono

I'm getting this exception on any HTTPS connection attempt. I've executed the `sudo mozroots --import --ask-remove` command as recommended, but still getting this error.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was necessary to run it without sudo.